# How to loop through multiple input lines in Java

Tags: java, loops, input, java.util.scanner

For this problem, I need to find the distance between two points given the coordinates of both points and the value p using a formula. I got the program to work for one input line but I want the user to be able to enter multiple lines and have the program loop through them. So for example:

1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 1.0

1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0

could be the input and the program would read both lines and give two different distance values. I was wondering, how can I have the scanner read multiple lines of input and then loop through them? This is the code I have now :

```
public class Driver_lab3{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 2 coordinate points and a p value, as follows : x1 y1 x2 y2 p : ");
    String coordinatestring = input.nextLine();

    int stringposition = 0;
    double x1 = 0.0;
    double x2 = 0.0;
    double y1 = 0.0;
    double y2 = 0.0;
    double p = 0.0;
    String temp = "temp";
    String spacecheck = "space";
    String subb4decimal = "temp sub";
    String subafterdecimal = "temp sub2";
    int decimalpos = 0;
    int spacepos = 0;
    double distance;


      if(Character.isDigit(coordinatestring.charAt(stringposition))){
        decimalpos = coordinatestring.indexOf('.', stringposition);
        subb4decimal = coordinatestring.substring(stringposition, decimalpos);
        spacepos = coordinatestring.indexOf(' ', decimalpos);
        subafterdecimal = coordinatestring.substring(decimalpos, spacepos);

        temp = subb4decimal + subafterdecimal;
        x1 = Double.parseDouble(temp);
        stringposition = spacepos + 1;

        decimalpos = coordinatestring.indexOf('.', stringposition);
        subb4decimal = coordinatestring.substring(stringposition, decimalpos);
        spacepos = coordinatestring.indexOf(' ', decimalpos);
        subafterdecimal = coordinatestring.substring(decimalpos, spacepos);

        temp = subb4decimal + subafterdecimal;
        y1 = Double.parseDouble(temp);
        stringposition = spacepos + 1;

        decimalpos = coordinatestring.indexOf('.', stringposition);
        subb4decimal = coordinatestring.substring(stringposition, decimalpos);
        spacepos = coordinatestring.indexOf(' ', decimalpos);
        subafterdecimal = coordinatestring.substring(decimalpos, spacepos);

        temp = subb4decimal + subafterdecimal;
        x2 = Double.parseDouble(temp);
        stringposition = spacepos + 1;

        decimalpos = coordinatestring.indexOf('.', stringposition);
        subb4decimal = coordinatestring.substring(stringposition, decimalpos);
        spacepos = coordinatestring.indexOf(' ', decimalpos);
        subafterdecimal = coordinatestring.substring(decimalpos, spacepos);

        temp = subb4decimal + subafterdecimal;
        y2 = Double.parseDouble(temp);
        stringposition = spacepos + 1;

        decimalpos = coordinatestring.indexOf('.', stringposition);
        subb4decimal = coordinatestring.substring(stringposition, decimalpos);
        spacepos = coordinatestring.indexOf(' ', decimalpos);
        subafterdecimal = coordinatestring.substring(decimalpos, spacepos);

        temp = subb4decimal + subafterdecimal;
        p = Double.parseDouble(temp);
        stringposition = spacepos + 1;

        distance = Math.pow(((Math.pow((Math.abs(x1-x2)),p)) + (Math.pow((Math.abs(y1-y2)),p))),(1.0/p));
        System.out.println(distance);
        System.out.println(x1);
        System.out.println(x2);
        System.out.println(y1);
        System.out.println(y2);
        System.out.println(p);

        stringposition = 0;
      }
  }
}
```

I am fairly new to java and still learning so I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just read another line using `input.nextLine` and process it the same way you did the first line.

Comment: What kind of loop you use depends on how you want to end the loop. Do you want to do it a fixed number of times, or do you want to exit the loop when the user types in some sentinel value.

Comment: You should move the code that processes each line into a method.  If you're using an IDE like Eclipse it will do it for you pretty painlessly.

Comment: Also, you could simplify your processing of the line using the `split`method of the String class to split your space-separated line into an array of strings and call `parseDouble`on each string.

Comment: Also, `Double.parseDouble` can throw a `NumberFormatException` so you might want to handle that gracefully using a try-catch block.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE]. To demonstrate "loop through multiple input lines in Java" you don't need all this code.

Answer (score 0):

first you can use `input.nextDouble()` to get double value and you can use `try` `catch` to handle incorrect input and you can use for loop to iterate over the inputs

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfInputs; i++){
            try{
                x1 = s.nextDouble();
                y1 = s.nextDouble();
                x2 = s.nextDouble();
                y2 = s.nextDouble();
                p = s.nextDouble();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {     
                System.out.println("Incorrect input");
            }

        // your logic here

  distance = Math.pow(((Math.pow((Math.abs(x1-x2)),p)) + (Math.pow((Math.abs(y1-y2)),p))),(1.0/p));
        System.out.println(distance);
        System.out.println(x1);
        System.out.println(x2);
        System.out.println(y1);
        System.out.println(y2);
        System.out.println(p);      
}
```